# Formula For Calculating Length Of Line In BMP Image using c#

Tags: c#, math, image-processing, graph

I want to calculate the length of some lines in this BMP [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DdLa.jpg).

I do not know the formula how to calculate these type of lines ? Or there is any other formula to calculate length in image processing.

By searching I came to know that we have to +1 in length if line if it go 1 pixel long vertically or horizontally. What if length is increasing diagonally ?
If any one can provide a mathematical formula that would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: It might not be optimal, but just check if there's a pixel the same color(if you're working with this kind of lines) on every pixel surrounding the first one.

Comment: Currently! I've only black lines, I've traced down line pixel by pixel too. But I do not know the formula to calculate length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length when the direction is 1 pixel in diagonal is 1.4142135623730950488016887242097.

The math behind this factor is plain vector math, let me explain. According to vector math we can compute the length of a 2D vector as `Math.Sqrt(Vector.X * Vector.X + Vector.Y * Vector.Y))`. If we take as origin (0,0) and as target (1,1) we know the distance vector between origin and target is (1,1). So, if we compute the length of this vector we get: `sqrt(1 * 1 + 1 * 1)` what reduced is `sqrt(2)` and yields a result of 1.4142135623730950488016887242097.

You can use vector math to calculate a bunch of pixels instead of adding this factor to achieve a better precission, to do this just apply the previous math:

```
distanceVector = targetVector - originVector
distance = sqrt(distanceVector.X * distanceVector.X + distanceVector.Y * distanceVector.Y)
```

If you use the System.Numeric package then you can use the integrated functions:

```
Vector2 origin = new Vector2(originPixelX, originPixelY);
Vector2 target = new Vector2(targetPixelX, targetPixelY);

Vector2 distanceVector = target - origin;
float length = distanceVector.Length();
```

EDIT:

To simplify your problem there is a very easy solution which will give you the best precission.

If you sum the total of straight pixels and diagonal pixels in two variables, let's name those straightPixels and diagonalPixels you can do this:

```
var length = straightPixels + (new Vector2(diagonalPixels, diagonalPixels)).Length();
```

If you don't want to use the System.Numeric you can do:

```
var length = straightPixels + Math.Sqrt(diagonalPixels * diagonalPixels + diagonalPixels * diagonalPixels);
```

Very simple and effective.

Comment: Thanks for the information, so it is simply adding sqrt(2) for diagonal pixel,
Can you ensure me one thing, for example I've this situation. 1 pixel at (0,0) second at (1,1) third at(2,2) and fourth at (3,3) so will my length formula will be ? length = sqrt(2) + sqrt(2) + sqrt(2);

Comment: Don't do just adding `sqrt(2)`, it will give you a very poor precission, use the vector math instead.

Comment: Let me add a method what will give you the best precission and is very easy using the System.Numeric package.

Comment: Only mathematical formula will be appreciated I'll try to convert it into code by my self. @Gusman

Answer (score 1):

If you want only lenght of diagonal for 1 pixel up and right, then it is [very simple](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=formula%20of%20length%20of%20diagonal%20of%20square&*).
So it will be square of two.

Comment: if I have a diagonal line with pixels then I'll have to add sqrt(2) pixels times ? this will be the correct length ?